# Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1, but it isn't

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

So, I have read a lot of questions here, and I have found out that I shold change my android manifest. So now my android:versionCode = "2"
But still, when I try to upload the updated apk, I get the error in the title.

I am making a game in unity, using the plugin for Google mobile ads.

Comment: I don't know how unity looks like. Does it work with gradle files? Because in Android Studio you have to change version in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Version Code gets probably overridden by the one in the [PlayerSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2S9G.png)

Comment: changing the numbers in PlayerSettings worked :) thanks

Comment: @Emil00 Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to accept this answer if it solved your problem, by clicking the gray checkmark next to it. This way, it signals to other people that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the version code in the `build.gradle` file as well :-)

Comment: I don't think this is true. If you supply a versionCode in your build.gradle, it will simply override anything in your Manifest (and it will give you a warning telling you that). If you don't supply one in your gradle file, the one from your manifest will be used. But you should never need both.

Comment: Yes, I simply assumed that the OP does not know about Gradle one, as they are only refering to Manifest, and Gradle value is created by default.